# Button Coming after taking mouse on it in Java GUI (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class null_login_type extends JFrame{

    private JLabel admin_password_label,heading,login_label,password_label,id_label;
    private JButton user_login_button,admin_login_button,enquiry_button,logins1,signup;
    private JTextField user_field,password_field,admin_field,admin_password_field;
    private ButtonGroup bg;
    null_login_type()
    {
        this.setLayout(null);
        user_login_button = new JButton("Login as User");
        logins1 = new JButton("Login");
        user_field = new JTextField("User_field");
        id_label = new JLabel("Id_label");


        user_login_button.setBounds(0,100, 150, 30);
        logins1.setBounds(250,200,100,30);
        user_field.setBounds(200,60,150,30); 

        add(user_login_button);

        event e = new event();
        user_login_button.addActionListener(e);
    }
    public class event implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            logins1.setBounds(250,60,150,30);; 
           // user_field.setBounds(250,60,150,30);;
           // add(user_field);
            add(logins1);
            logins1.setVisible(true);
        }   
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        null_login_type gui = new null_login_type();

        gui.setSize(420,300);
        gui.setLocation(530,200);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;

    }
}
```

Else the button is not visible.
When I take mouse on logins1 area the button comes and it is there then.

If I add the commented section in the action listener and remove the logins1 in action listener, the output is printed even if I don't take mouse on it.

Comment: You need to create all your GUI in the event dispatcher thread, have a look at `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater() will make button to come later . But i want buttonlogins1 to come as soon as i click user_login_button

Comment: You really should make use of a LayoutManager; using a null layout and trying to place child components yourself is quite difficult. Pixel-perfect placement is nearly impossible since it depends on the font and L&F that is being used, and doesn't respond well when the user resizes the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the content of something you need to call `repaint()` and `revalidate()`, see just after. You also need to create your GUI in the EDT, and use a `Panel` in your `JFrame` (always better than rely on the default):

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class null_login_type extends JFrame{    
  private JLabel admin_password_label,heading,login_label,password_label,id_label;
  private JButton user_login_button,admin_login_button,enquiry_button,logins1,signup;
  private JTextField user_field,password_field,admin_field,admin_password_field;
  private ButtonGroup bg;
  private JPanel panel;
  null_login_type()
  {
    panel = new JPanel();
    this.setContentPane(panel);
    this.setLayout(null);
    user_login_button = new JButton("Login as User");
    logins1 = new JButton("Login");
    user_field = new JTextField("User_field");
    id_label = new JLabel("Id_label");        
    user_login_button.setBounds(0,100, 150, 30);
    logins1.setBounds(250,200,100,30);
    user_field.setBounds(200,60,150,30);         
    panel.add(user_login_button);       
    event e = new event();
    user_login_button.addActionListener(e);
  }
  public class event implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){          
      logins1.setBounds(250,60,150,30);; 
      // user_field.setBounds(250,60,150,30);;
      // add(user_field);
      panel.add(logins1);
      panel.repaint();
      panel.revalidate();
    }   
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          null_login_type gui = new null_login_type();          
          gui.setSize(420,300);
          gui.setLocation(530,200);
          gui.setVisible(true);
          gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Please also use standard convention to name your classes, i.e. `NullLoginType`. Don't call your inner class `event`, there exists an `Event` class, choose something more appropriate, it doesn't represent an event but an event handler...